# method:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: does not call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, push-notification

I have written the code of push notification in my app as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     [Parse setApplicationId:kPARSEAPPID clientKey:kPARSECLIENTKEY];
     // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound]; 
}
```

But in following method control does not go.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *str = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(@"str=%@",str);
    [PFPush storeDeviceToken:deviceToken];

}
```

what should be the problem with my code?
Any idea?

thanx in advance...

Comment: Also ade the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error` method to your app delegate. Also did you create the correct profisioning files for the app.

Comment: I have done what you have mentioned.